# Android navigation drawer image animation

Tags: android, android-animation, material-design

I'm working navigation drawer.i successfully create id and i can use it.now i want to use navigation drawer's iamge animation

[i mean this animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heEtR.gif)

i searched and i found one github project

> https://github.com/markushi/android-ui

I did not understood it.i want to use this animation in my own image.
it's  a possible to use this  animation with my own image?
if anyone knows another examples  please help me
thanks everyone

Comment: where do you want the animation image to be? If you have done some thing on it share it , it would be easier to understand what are you up  to

Comment: Simple .in screen center i have one imageview and in my imageview has some background and in button click i want to  change background like this video @johnrao07

Comment: What is the guarantee that you would be able to understand examples if we  share!

Comment: i want this animation https://raw.githubusercontent.com/markushi/android-ui/master/example-action.gif

Comment: i found one example in github but i can't run it https://github.com/markushi/android-ui @PareshMayani Mayani

Comment: @PareshMayani Mayani i updated my question please see my new links

Comment: your new link does what you're looking for. So what's the issue here?

Comment: @johnrao07 i can't run this app from github. in my studio log  message is . apk successfully  installed that's all

Comment: Read the instruction on how to run....you don't need to download it and run at all....read on how to use it..https://gist.github.com/markushi/68ce8df77bed164b6275  and the rest detaills are in the link you specified

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: You don't need to reinvent the wheel. Android Studio has inbuilt support for navigation drawer. Here how to get it:
1. Use Android Studio -> Update to latest version 1.4
2. While Creating new project -> Choose Navigation Drawer Activity

You'll get the exact animation inbuilt

Comment: this is a perfect way but  i want only image rotate animation... how i can  solve my problem ?